# Facebook Unity SDK has some large files

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

Facebook Unity SDK has some large files that I wonder if I even need. Git is giving me warning when I'm trying to commit them and I also don't want to make my repo larger.

This file is 20MB: FacebookSDK\Plugins\iOS\FBSDKCoreKit.framework
This file is 15MB: FacebookSDK\Plugins\iOS\FBSDKShareKit.framework

I was wondering if I need these files when all I'm using from the Facebook Unity SDK is a simple Facebook Login feature and nothing else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you have ever try the below or find a work around. The SDK is very bulky and can't see how it could be so big.

Comment: It's been a while so I don't quite remember but I'm pretty sure I just followed the suggestion in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will need the CoreKit framework at the very least, that is what handles all the login authentication etc. As for ShareKit, my guess would be that there is code in the examples folder that references functions in that framework that you would also need to remove at the very least, but the CoreKit might also have built in references to the ShareKit framework, so you might be stuck with it. Try removing the ShareKit framework and all the example scripts and make a build and see what happens.